# Android Push notification without user interaction

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

After some searching for my question "Android Push notification without user interaction?" I cant seem to find an answer..

There seems to be some conflicting answers in this post:
[Push Notification without user interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682430/push-notification-without-user-interaction)

But this is for iOS.

So anybody who can give me the answer, without a user clicking on the notification, can it be intercepted in onMessage in android and then be used to run some code, like start the GPS and play a sound, if its in the background?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken Android push notifications differ significantly from iOS ones. There is no such thing as 'automated push notification'. Instead every developer receives the notification for their own application and has to add the notification for the user by themselves. So yes, if you are developer of the application receiving the push notification you should be able to run pretty much any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive GCM messages those are intercepted by a `BroadcastReceiver` registered in your manifest file. What you do when such a message is received is completely up to you. It is not mandatory to show a notification whenever a GCM message arrives. In fact, many applications make all sorts of transparent uses of GCM, but you should always be mindful about battery consumption when it comes to that.

Cheers.

Comment: Yes, as @Tom has said, you can do whatever you want onMessage method of GCMBaseIntentService class. Is not mandatory to generate notification in notification bar.